# Is there a .NET library for sending keystrokes, mouse clicks, mouse movements and other input? Similar to AutoHotKey but for .NET library use?

Tags: .net, hook, autohotkey, keyboard-hook, mouse-hook

I'm looking to essentially write code similar to what I can do with [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), only in .NET and C#, because it's a much more robust environment.  I didn't know if there was a wrapper library available for these sorts of hooks or not.

Does anyone know of a library that does this for .NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/InputManager.aspx) actually looks pretty promising, I haven't tested it yet, but it's at least a good starting point. Not too bad considering it's on CodeProject. lol.

Answer (score 0):

For sending keys you can use [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx).

For mouse and other input you have to wrap the [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950%28VS.85%29.aspx) API.